# SQLAlchemy with Sqlite ON DELETE,UPDATE CASCADE not working

Tags: sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy as ORM in flask with sqlite as DB for my web application.

I've 4 tables in my DB and I wanna implement ON DELETE CASCADE, ON UPDATE CASCADE correctly.

My relationships are :

**Table Student and Subject has 1-to-many relationship with table Major**

**Table Mark is an association table between Table Subject and Student**

so the expected behavior is :

- When I delete,update a Student or Subject the correspending line gots deleted from table Mark(association table).
- When I delete,update a Major the correspending line gots deleted from tables Student and Subject.

These are my classes :

```
class Student(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'Student'
   .......
    major_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Major.id')) 


class Subject(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'Subject'
    .......
    major_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Major.id')) 
  

class Mark(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'Mark'
   .....
    stdnt_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('Student.regNumber'))
    subj_id = db.Column(db.String(5),db.ForeignKey('Subject.code'))
    .......


class Major(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'Major'
    ............
    students = db.relationship('Student', backref='major', lazy='dynamic')
    subjects = db.relationship('Subject', backref='major', lazy='dynamic')
```

**I've tried** : `onupdate="cascade",ondelete="cascade",cascade="all,delete, delete-orphan",passive_deletes=True`............
and tested them in my web app but to no avail.

**NB**: I've checked my sqlite database file sometimes and found ON DELETE,UPDATE CASCASE constraints added to my db scheme but the cascade not working from my wep app.

Please any help ?

Comment: Please see [Foreign Key Support](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html#foreign-key-support) part of the documentation

Answer (score 1):

I tried and test many links and can't delete the parent. until I get one of the link that can delete the parent and automatically delete all its children. but can't update. here is the simplified code below,

```
class Parent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = db.relationship(
        "Child", back_populates="parent",
        cascade="all, delete",
        passive_deletes=True
    )

class Child(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('parent.id', ondelete="CASCADE"))
    parent = db.relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")
```